# Library can be used to generate pdf offline ios(native)

Tags: ios, iphone, itext

I want to be generate pdf offline in ios. 
Does iText give library of that?I found that iText give libraries for andoid, java and C#. I used it for android and java (server side).

Comment: That's a question you should ask sales@itextpdf.com. Why? Because there currently isn't a Swift or Objective-C port of iText, but if there is sufficient demand from customers (not just free AGPL users but actual customers that pay for a license) that warrants the porting cost, then this might change. So my question to you is: if there were an iOS version of iText, would you buy it or would you use it for free?

Comment: I had android and java(licence). So I would buy it but problem statement is  that is it available or not?

Comment: That question has already been answered in my first comment. Currently, May 2016, there is no iOS version of iText. If you want one, ask sales, don't ask on StackOverflow, because it's not a technical question. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Oh and one more thing: the license of the Apple app store contradicts the GPL, and most certainly also the AGPL.  I am not a lawyer so do not take this as legal advice, but I think there would be legal issues with having iText on iOS. Read this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6109

Answer (score 4):

iOS, unlike Android, has a native way to create PDF documents - and it's actually quite clever. You can create a PDF context via CoreGraphics   and then use that to draw into - just like you would draw into a regular image context. It will correctly write text as text, so you get the benefits of sharp text even at high zoom levels.

Here's how this looks in Objective-C:

```
NSString *pdfFileName = [self getPDFFileName];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

// draw into the context
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[@"My PDF file title" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100) withFont:font];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

You can learn more in Apple's [Creating PDF Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) documentation. Now fair warning, Apple's PDF engine is not quite on top of their list, and there are many aspects that you cannot control well, such as image compression, PDF version or metadata like page labels, a PDF outline, PDF annotations or even forms.

I've been working with my team for the past 5 years on an alternative, commercial SDK named PSPDFKit that is more flexible and allows all of the above both on iOS and Android and soon also for the browser. See [PSPDFNewPageConfiguration](https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFNewPageConfiguration.html) for a start.